# Dictionary of list's, where list's have dictionary's

Tags: python, list, dictionary, for-loop, if-statement

following is the dictionary of list's where list's have dictionary's

```
dict4 =  {
    234: [{'apple': 87}, {'fan': 88}, {'jackal': 89}],
    345: [{'bat': 98}, {'car': 84}, {'ice': 80}],
    456: [{'car': 86}, {'apple': 82}, {'goat': 80}],
    567: [{'dog': 81}, {'cat': 80}, {'eagle': 90}],
    678: [{'eagle': 98}, {'hawk': 89}, {'dog': 79}],
    789: [{'fan': 89}, {'goat': 84}, {'car': 81}],
    890: [{'hawk': 90}, {'ice': 85}, {'cat': 78}],
    901: [{'goat': 85}, {'jackal': 90}, {'apple': 80}],
    123: [{'ice': 87}, {'bat': 94}, {'bat': 92}],
    546: [{'jackal': 91}, {'eagle': 93}, {'fan': 85}]
}
```

In the above `dict4`, apple(as the sub-key) is present three times at different places i.e., (`{'apple': 87},{'apple': 82}, {'apple': 80}`) , I would like to keep apple with highest value (`{'apple': 87}`) , and omit the rest from `dict4` and same applies to all other sub-keys.

Final output dict should look like

```
dict4 =  {
    234: [{'apple': 87}],
    345: [{'bat': 98}],
    456: [{'car': 86}],
    567: [{'dog': 81}, {'cat': 80}],
    678: [{'eagle': 98}],
    789: [{'fan': 89}],
    890: [{'hawk': 90}],
    901: [{'goat': 85}],
    123: [{'ice': 87}],
    546: [{'jackal': 91}]
}
```

I can not think of way to approach the problem, any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated

Thank you!

Comment: I would write a function to "swap" the key of dict4 with the key of the sub-dictionaries and their locations - something that outputs `dict4_t = {'apple': [(234, 87), (456, 82), (901, 80)], 'bat': [(345, 98), (123, 94), (123, 92)], ...}` then just take the maximum based on the second value for each key and convert back (like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73959710/5358968) but with more steps)

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a dictionary to store the max value of each key.

1. Initialize an empty dict `temp`.
2. Then for each key `key1` in `dict4`, iterate over the list corresponding to `key1`.
3. For each element in the list, if the key (for example apple) doesn't exist in `temp`, save the key and the corresponding value in `temp`. Else, store the larger value in `temp`
4. Now that you have `temp`, create new dict `dict5`. Iterate over `dict4` and for each key `key1` in `dict4`, only store the elements of the list which match both key and value in `temp`
5. Return `dict5`

Answer (score 1):

Iterate your structure and create a mapping `sub-key => (super-key, value)` where value is the max among the same subkey:

```
maxes = {}

for main_key, ls in dict4.items():
    for sub_key, val in ls[0].items():
        if sub_key not in maxes or maxes[sub_key][1] < val:
            maxes[sub_key] = (main_key, val)

print(maxes)
```

This creates a dict like

```
{'apple': (234, 87), 'bat': (345, 98), 'car': (456, 86), 'dog': (567, 81), 'eagle': (678, 98), 'fan': (789, 89), 'hawk': (890, 90), 'goat': (901, 85), 'ice': (123, 87), 'jackal': (546, 91)}
```

It should be easy to derive your desired structure from this.